# Simpy how to access objects in a resource queue

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am moving code written in Simpy 2 to version 3 and could not find an equivalent to the following operation.

In the code below I access job objects (derived from class job_(Process)) in a Simpy resource's activeQ.

```
def select_LPT(self, mc_no):
    job = 0
    ptime = 0
    for j in buffer[mc_no].activeQ:
        if j.proc_time[mc_no] > ptime:
            ptime = j.proc_time[mc_no]
            job = j

    return job
```

To do this in Simpy 3, I tried the following

`buffers[mc_no].users`

which returns a list of Request() objects. With these objects I cannot access the processes that created them, nor the objects these process functions belong to. (using the 'put_queue', and 'get_queue' of the Resource object did not help)

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SimPy, request objects do not know which process created them.  However, since we are in Python land you can easily add this information:

```
with resource.request() as req:
    req.obj = self
    yield req
    ...

 # In another process/function
 for user_req in resource.users:
     print(user_req.obj)
```

Comment: Long live the land of Python ! - Thank you. I have a follow up question:  I have a job class that has a process function go() - as in Simpy 2. With req.obj = self I stick the object data, now how to I stick the process data. I need it because I want to interrupt the process and have the job object resume its flow.

Comment: Never mind - figured it out. Just create the process in the constructor of the object, keep it as an attribute, then access through the job object.

Comment: uh ah, do you have an example for that? @Suleyman Karabuk